# Hadoop v/s Spark clarification

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

I'm studying about Hadoop and Spark and landed into one doubt. Please help me to clarify that.

Hadoop reads from HDFS(Hard disk) and process data in memory and write the produced output back to HDFS(Hard Disk). Correct me if am wrong here.

Sparks will also read data from Hard disk(else where it could be at first time ?) and fill those data into RDD (created in memory) and then do processing and later write that data to Hard disk if not further processing is required. In spark multiple RDDs can be created to deal with different type processing of data. And those RDDs can interacts with each other. Correct me if am wrong here.

Spark is recommended for real time processing. Why ? Can't be same thing done by Hadoop ? Because at the end, source and destination is Hard disk.(If any other situation exists, please share). In hadoop I can't create RDDs like concept but I can extend my code which will do the same thing as multiple RDDs are doing.(Make sense)

Please share your views on my thoughts and correct me wherever am wrong.

Comment: Maybe this will help a little: https://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-spark-vs-hadoop-mapreduce. I have not worked on either framework. But, it looks like Spark processes data faster than hadoop.

Comment: Read page 1 and 2 of the RDD paper here - https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2011/EECS-2011-82.pdf - compares RDD with others very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

> Because at the end, source and destination is Hard disk.

Sure, but not necessarily a HDFS hard disk. Could be a Mysql server or Kafka Broker.

> Spark is recommended for real time processing. Why ? Can't be same thing done by Hadoop ?

First, Hadoop isn't a processing engine - YARN provides the abstraction for job processing, and many applications run on YARN. Including Flink, Storm/Heron, which are the lesser referenced (not sure why?) actual real-time streaming platforms (usually loaded by Kafka, not Hadoop). Spark does "mini batches" on the orders of seconds at a minimum, where the other frameworks operates on even smaller time frames

> In hadoop I can't create RDDs like concept

RDD is a Spark concept, and Spark leverages Hadoop libraries to perform its tasks, so that statement is false.

If you mean you can't create lazily computed actions, then you might want to look at Pig, which also creates a DAG execution plan that is only computed when an action is performed. Much like how RDD (or DataFrames) interact with each other.

> Sparks will also read data from Hard disk(else where it could be at first time ?)

Assuming you mean HDFS hard disks, alternatives could be local filesystem, S3, Kafka, as mentioned, or a SQL database, or Mongo, Elasticsearch, etc. Hadoop is just one possible place where data exists and Spark can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Spark and Hadoop are not equivalent. RDD is a concept purely from Spark framework that can map files sored in HDFS. Spark could process and never write to Disks, merely like a mean of transit.

Hadoop is conformed by HDFS plus YARN. HDFS is aimed to provide distributed storage leveraging from Disks, while YARN enable you to use infraestructure for processing RAM. Spark can access both of them.

I think your need make at least two examples to understand how Spark and Hadoop are related:

- [Install a Hadoop cluster](https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-hadoop-single-node-hadoop-cluster)
- Execute a [Spark WordCount example](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html)

Comment: "Spark could process and never write to Disks", Can you share any example, where storing of data is not required in disk after processing ?

Comment: @Elena If you write results to an external file system or network channel, it's taken from memory, and doesn't write to HDFS disks

Comment: Uses cases that use Kafka. Spark reads from Kafka and also can write to kafka. Tibco, Pubsub are other examples.

Comment: @cricket_007, Whether its a external file system or network channel, dont you think so its gonna be disk at the end where it going to be written ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: Those kind of services use Disks for its own purposes, for fault tolerance and reliability for example. But its functionality uses memory to provide performance and high availability, and so on. From the point of view that you are sharing every system in the world uses disks, in that sens RAM would also be a small disk.